# The property 'ServiceManifestVersion' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set

Tags: xml, powershell, azure-service-fabric

I want to update the XML file using the Powershell. I want to update the ServiceManifestVersion to some value.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationManifest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ApplicationTypeName="AvatarPoc.FabricType" ApplicationTypeVersion="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="AzureCosmosMongoDbConnectionString" DefaultValue="WillBeSetBeforeDeployment" />
    <Parameter Name="AzureServiceBusConnectionString" DefaultValue="WillBeSetBeforeDeployment" />
    <Parameter Name="AzureAppInsightsInstrumentationKey" DefaultValue="WillBeSetBeforeDeployment" />
    <Parameter Name="SignalRAzureServiceBusTopicPrefix" DefaultValue="WillBeSetBeforeDeployment" />
    <Parameter Name="SignalREncryptionKey" DefaultValue="WillBeSetBeforeDeployment" />
  </Parameters>
  <!-- Import the ServiceManifest from the ServicePackage. The ServiceManifestName and ServiceManifestVersion         should match the Name and Version attributes of the ServiceManifest element defined in the         ServiceManifest.xml file. -->
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="AvatarPoc.AudioDeviceActorPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides>
      <ConfigOverride Name="Config">
        <Settings>
          <Section Name="AppConfig">
            <Parameter Name="AzureCosmosMongoDbConnectionString" Value="[AzureCosmosMongoDbConnectionString]" />
            <Parameter Name="AzureAppInsightsInstrumentationKey" Value="[AzureAppInsightsInstrumentationKey]" />
          </Section>
        </Settings>
      </ConfigOverride>
    </ConfigOverrides>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="AvatarPoc.PubSubActorPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides>
      <ConfigOverride Name="Config">
        <Settings>
          <Section Name="AppConfig">
            <Parameter Name="AzureServiceBusConnectionString" Value="[AzureServiceBusConnectionString]" />
            <Parameter Name="SignalRAzureServiceBusTopicPrefix" Value="[SignalRAzureServiceBusTopicPrefix]" />
            <Parameter Name="SignalREncryptionKey" Value="[SignalREncryptionKey]" />
            <Parameter Name="AzureAppInsightsInstrumentationKey" Value="[AzureAppInsightsInstrumentationKey]" />
          </Section>
        </Settings>
      </ConfigOverride>
    </ConfigOverrides>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="AvatarPoc.SignalPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides>
      <ConfigOverride Name="Config">
        <Settings>
          <Section Name="AppConfig">
            <Parameter Name="AzureServiceBusConnectionString" Value="[AzureServiceBusConnectionString]" />
            <Parameter Name="SignalRAzureServiceBusTopicPrefix" Value="[SignalRAzureServiceBusTopicPrefix]" />
            <Parameter Name="SignalREncryptionKey" Value="[SignalREncryptionKey]" />
            <Parameter Name="AzureAppInsightsInstrumentationKey" Value="[AzureAppInsightsInstrumentationKey]" />
          </Section>
        </Settings>
      </ConfigOverride>
    </ConfigOverrides>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="AvatarPoc.WebApiPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides>
      <ConfigOverride Name="Config">
        <Settings>
          <Section Name="AppConfig">
            <Parameter Name="AzureCosmosMongoDbConnectionString" Value="[AzureCosmosMongoDbConnectionString]" />
            <Parameter Name="AzureAppInsightsInstrumentationKey" Value="[AzureAppInsightsInstrumentationKey]" />
          </Section>
        </Settings>
      </ConfigOverride>
    </ConfigOverrides>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="AvatarPoc.ThingListenerPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides>
      <ConfigOverride Name="Config">
        <Settings>
          <Section Name="AppConfig">
            <Parameter Name="AzureCosmosMongoDbConnectionString" Value="[AzureCosmosMongoDbConnectionString]" />
            <Parameter Name="AzureAppInsightsInstrumentationKey" Value="[AzureAppInsightsInstrumentationKey]" />
          </Section>
        </Settings>
      </ConfigOverride>
    </ConfigOverrides>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <ServiceTemplates>
    <StatefulService ServiceTypeName="AudioDeviceActorServiceType">
      <UniformInt64Partition PartitionCount="1" LowKey="-9223372036854775808" HighKey="9223372036854775807" />
    </StatefulService>
    <StatefulService ServiceTypeName="PubSubActorServiceType">
      <UniformInt64Partition PartitionCount="1" LowKey="-9223372036854775808" HighKey="9223372036854775807" />
    </StatefulService>
    <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="SignalType">
      <SingletonPartition />
    </StatelessService>
    <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="WebApiType">
      <SingletonPartition />
    </StatelessService>
    <StatefulService ServiceTypeName="ThingListenerType">
      <UniformInt64Partition PartitionCount="4" LowKey="0" HighKey="3" />
    </StatefulService>
  </ServiceTemplates>
</ApplicationManifest>`
```

I am trying to update the values by using the following Code

```
$buildNo = "001"
$ApplicationManifestPath = "D:\New folder\new1.xml"
$ApplicationManifestString = [string] (Get-Content $ApplicationManifestPath)
$ApplicationManifestXml = [xml]$ApplicationManifestString
$applicationTypeVersionOld = [string]$ApplicationManifestXml.ApplicationManifest.ApplicationTypeVersion
$updatedVersionNumber  =[string] $applicationTypeVersionOld + "-" + $buildNo
$ServiceManifestVersions = $ApplicationManifestXml.ApplicationManifest.ServiceManifestImport.ChildNodes

foreach($ServiceManifestversion in $ServiceManifestVersions)
{
$ApplicationManifestXml.ApplicationManifest.ServiceManifestImport.ServiceManifestRef.ServiceManifestVersion = $updatedVersionNumber
}
$ApplicationManifestXml.Save("D:\New Folder\new 2 .xml")
```

While Setting the value I am getting the following error:

> The property 'ServiceManifestVersion' cannot be found on this object.
>   Verify that the property exists and can be set.

If I am able to update the values if I am keeping only one node but getting the error while running it on foreach loop.Also, I am able to get the values but not set it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your foreach to:

```
foreach ($ServiceManifestRef in $ApplicationManifestXml.ApplicationManifest.ServiceManifestImport.ServiceManifestRef)
{
    $ServiceManifestRef.SetAttribute('ServiceManifestVersion', $updatedVersionNumber)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The VSTS guys have some Tasks for this. They're [open source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/ServiceFabricUpdateManifests). You can use the tasks directly in VSTS or TFS, or use the code in your own solution. (it's MIT licensed)

Comment: That will help as well. I need to make few tweaks to it to work it with Bamboo but it will help me out. Appreciate your help :)